# Why is my code not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I just wrote this code and when I tested it, the javascript wouldn't work.
I have javascript enabled and I tried with a different code and it worked. I think there's maybe a bug but I can't see it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id=“id”>Some Text</p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById(“id”).innerHTML=“Different Text”;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste that code?  I can't even find smartquotes on my keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I copied it from the original file.

Answer (score 5):

You are using smart quotes (`“”`) instead of normal quotes (`""`). Replace the quotes and it will work.

```
<p id="id">Some Text</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="Different Text";
</script>
```

Perhaps this is because you are using a word processor, not an [IDE](http://google.com/search?q=html+and+javascript+IDE)?

Comment: I turned off the smart quotes and it works now. Thanks! Im using TextEdit.

Comment: @user2551603 Glad to help! You might want to consider using an IDE though; it would make it much easier.